# How to access multiple JSON lists in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, servlets

I have a Java servlet which does the following:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonObject.put("Status", status);
jsonObject.put("isActive", isActive);

jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
response.getWriter().write(jsonArray.toString());

//Now I have for loops here.

JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
DTO dtost = list.get(i);
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("Label",dtost.getLabel());
jsonObj.put("UNID",dtost.getUNID());

jsonArray2.add(jsonObj); 
}

response.getWriter().write(jsonArray2.toString());
```

I'm getting this JSON data and would like to know how to make this a correct JSON format, and to access the values inside using Javascript.

```
[{"Status":"Passed","isActive":"No"}] [{"Label":"MembershipCard","UNID":"01"},{"Label":"LoyaltyCard","UNID":"02"}]
```

I'm trying the following Javascript Code snippet but I am not retrieving any.

```
success: function(data) {

  alert(data[0].Status); // Nothing
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `[{"Status":"Passed","isActive":"No"}] [{"Label":"MembershipCard","UNID":"01"},{"Label":"LoyaltyCard","UNID":"02"}]` is not valid json

Comment: I see no relation to Java or servlets here.

Comment: Your data example is invalid. There's basically 2 JSON arrays, while only one is considered valid JSON

Comment: Hi, I am retrieving the Json data from a Java servlet.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned is an invalid JSON.
However if we modify the JSON to this
"**[[{"Status":"Passed","isActive":"No"}], [{"Label":"MembershipCard","UNID":"01"},{"Label":"LoyaltyCard","UNID":"02"}]]**"
then it is a valid JSON.

So to access Status parameter of the above data something like this:-

`success: function(data){

    alert(data[0][0].Status);

}`

Comment: Hi @neeraj, I updated my code, how will I be able to retrieve this kind of JSON result? Thank you.

Comment: So basically the 2 arrays **[{"Status":"Passed","isActive":"No"}] ** and **[{"Label":"MembershipCard","UNID":"01"},{"Label":"LoyaltyCard","UNID":"02"}]** need to be put together inside an array to make it a valid JSON. Something like this--> [arr1,arr2]. So it'll yield you the JSON data that i mentioned above, then you can easily access it

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your java code to generate valid json object.
`{"first":[{"Status":"Passed","isActive":"No"}],"second":[{"Label":"MembershipCard","UNID":"01"},{"Label":"LoyaltyCard","UNID":"02"}]}`

```
JSONObject output= new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonObject.put("Status", status);
jsonObject.put("isActive", isActive);

jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
output.put("first", jsonArray);

//Now I have for loops here.

JSONArray jsonArray2 = new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
DTO dtost = list.get(i);
 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("Label",dtost.getLabel());
jsonObj.put("UNID",dtost.getUNID());

jsonArray2.add(jsonObj); 
}
output.put("second", jsonArray2);
response.getWriter().write(output.toString());
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this. I am able to retrieve data in the format: `{"second":[{"Label":"MembershipCard","UNID":"01"}],{"first":[{"Status":"Passed","isActive":"No"}]}`

May I ask how will I be able to retrieve data from first and second? for example I would like to access the Status from first?

Comment: @Ragome - Let's say you want to fetch all the object where the key is Status. `let pluckKeys = (input, key) => {
 if(!input){
  return [];
 }
 return Object.keys(input).reduce((out,k) => {
  if(!input[k]){
   return out;
  }
  let values = input[k];
  if(values instanceof Array){
   out = out.concat(values.filter((val) => {
    return val.hasOwnProperty(key);
   }));
  }
  return out;
 },[]);
};
`.  Pass the output from your java code into this function - pluckKeys({"second":[{"Label":"MembershipCard","UNID":"01"}],{"first":[{"Status":"Passed","isActive":"No"}]},"Status");